# Unable to build and create apk file in Cordova project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, apache-cordova

In visual studio 2015 When I try to create apk file, I got the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       cmd: Command failed with exit code 1    BlankCordovaApp2
Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\
ERROR building one of the platforms 1`
```

Here is my output:

```
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c 
""C:\Users\Programming\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test 
Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\gradlew"
cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\Programming\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test 
Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\build.gradle" -
Dorg.gradle.daemon=true" (TaskId:11)
1>  Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c  
""C:\Users\Programming\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test 
Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat" -
-debug "--buildConfig=C:\Users\Programming\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\Test Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\build.json"" 
(TaskId:11)
1>ERROR building one of the platforms : error : cmd: Command failed with exit    
code 1
1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project   
(TaskId:11)
1>MDAVSCLI : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
1>Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED. (TaskId:11)
1>Done building target "BuildMDA" in project "BlankCordovaApp2.jsproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:11)
```

---

I've also opened up the SDK manager  without any problem and reinstall nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the build from the command line (or maybe increasing the verbosity level of the output window).  You should get a more detailed error from the command line where it is failing.

In SDK manager did you make sure you installed any available updates that are shown?  Did you install a new plugin in the app that might require additional libraries like Play Services?